# logic app to read multiple blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am designing an azure logic app to get a latest added blob in the container from list of blobs in a container to proceed further.

[image]

My scenario is, if n files are added into the container path `/destinationcontainer` then i need to store into sql server using azure functions and delete it after the successful insertion using logic app.

I want to get all the blobs which are there inside the container at a single stretch using `/*.txt or /*.csv` filename extensions.

as follows:
[image]

Is there any better way to get things done?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scenario, if two blobs are added since the last time, do you only care about the last blob, not both?

Comment: @DerekLi I added my exact scenario in the question section above.

Comment: Besed on my experience, we also could do this with [Azure function blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob).

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT : Thanks buddy,I resolved it with simple blob trigger option of Logic app. I added the same in my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the solution, the problem is not with the azure blob trigger and its with only the approach of solving it.

the blob trigger will automatically detects the `/destinationcontainer` path we given and report the recently added blob's metadata information such as,

```
"Id": "xxxxxxsadasdaasd=",
  "Name": "text.txt",
  "DisplayName": "text.txt",
  "Path": "/destinationcontainer/text.txt",
  "LastModified": "2017-07-19T09:16:41Z",
  "Size": 208078,
  "MediaType": "text/plain",
  "IsFolder": false,
  "ETag": "\"0xcv234232ssd\"",
  "FileLocator": "xxxxxxsadasdaasd=",
  "LastModifiedBy": null
```

by using the above meta data information, we can get the `File Content` of a recent blob.

My final flow of logic app will be,
[image]

Thanks all for your valuable insight.

Comment: can you get the trigger if blob file is in a sub-folder of container?

Comment: @SILENCE there is an open issue here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20164843-azure-storage-blob-trigger-to-fire-when-files-adde

Comment: will this spin up a separate version of the logic app for every single indiviual blob added?

Comment: still not sure how you are getting the file content